# Query regarding the DeviceID

Tags: windows-phone-7

There are 2 queries: First I was able to retrieve the DeviceUniqueID from the DeviceExtendedProperties. It gives me a byte array of 20 bytes in length. I was only able to convert it into a base64 string to make it readable. What is the actual way to make the byte array readable ? Second I registered my WP7 device using ActiveSync and the deviceID that i received from the device was XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDFA720 which consists of 32 characters. It is not same as the DeviceUniqueID. How can I get this deviceID from the device ?

Comment: the answers section is *only* for potential solutions to your problem.  If you want to add more information to your question, please use the edit link above this comment, just below your question's tags.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code to get the DeviceUniqueId as a formatted string:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the unique identifier for the device.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A string representation of the unique device identifier.
public static string GetDeviceId()
{
    byte[] uniqueId = (byte[])DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
    return BitConverter.ToString(uniqueId);
}
```

Not sure what you mean about using ActiveSync with WP7 devices. If you can give me some more details to repro, I might be able to help further.

Comment: By ActiveSync i meant that i registered my wp7 device on a mail exchange server. My server received a deviceID which was not the same as compared to the deviceUniqueID.

Answer (score 1):

Wndows Phone 7 does not work with ActiveSync (or Windows Mobile Device Center).

Your 32 char ID is probably the ANID or Anonymized ID (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.trygetvalue(v=VS.92).aspx)